# How to convert a timestamp data type into integer millisecond in python

Tags: python

I have my date and time field in the form Timestamp('2016-12-02 22:25:44'). I want this to be converted to integer millisecond form in python. Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: What's `Timestamp`?

Comment: What do you mean by "integer millisecond form"? Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: Like milliseconds since 1970 or some epoch?

Comment: Is that your value a string `Timestamp('2016-12-02 22:25:44')` or a timestamp object with datetime '2016-12-02 22:25:44'?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Python is quite good at this. The following function worked for me in many cases.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('2016-12-02 22:25:44').strftime("%s")
```

(just read the comments, thought you meant a string, not sure if this answer applies to what you ask but seems not clear yet)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am getting the error "Invalid format string" if I use parse('2016-12-02 22:25:44').strftime("%s").

Comment: The above code works for me for python 2.7.5 and python 3.4.8. Not sure what else can go wrong.